# php renaming session ID

Tags: php

By default the initial PHP session ID is:PHPSESSID
However, when I change that to:YourVisit
and I click on Cookies, and view Cookie information
after submitting my form there are two
Cookies:
PHPSESSID and YourVisit, I thought there was only suppose to be one session ID?

This has been occurring even after hitting Clear Session Cookies button and verifying that there are no sessions before submitting the form, just wondering why this is happening (two session ID's), I only need one, disclaimer the values are different and thank you for not flaming the newb.

```
session_name('YourVisit');
session_start();
<?php
// Take the user's email and store it in a session.
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
// Take the time that the user logged in and store that also in a session.
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = time();
?>
```

Comment: Had another require('header.html'); with another session_start(), fixed, thank you guys for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old PHPSESSID was not removed. but it will be when expired.

If you visit after the change, PHPSESSID will not be set.

Comment: So I will probably just wait for about  30 min?

Comment: if not you can just remove it. It doesn't do any harm to the system.

Comment: Can't use this?
session_destroy();

Comment: How, do you remove it, apparently my 'lil' web developer add-on is not really
Clearing any session cookies, for whatever reasons.

Comment: Never-mind, I can delete the cookie and session, I think the problem might be my require section of code, sessions are pretty nifty.